# How to cross join two selects in H2

Tags: sql, h2

I'm trying to CROSS JOIN two simple query results in a H2 database:

```
SELECT *
FROM
       (
              SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY
              FROM GENERIC_RECORD
       ) 
       CROSS JOIN
       (    
              SELECT CAST( MONTH(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-' || CAST(YEAR(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS DATE
              FROM GENERIC_RECORD 
          GROUP BY CAST( MONTH(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-' || CAST(YEAR(LOCAL_DATE) AS VARCHAR(4))
       )
```

But I get the error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT
    ((CAST(MONTH(""LOCAL_DATE"") AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-') || CAST(YEAR(""LOCAL_DATE"") AS VARCHAR(4))) AS ""DATE""
FROM ""PUBLIC"".""GENERIC_RECORD""
GROUP BY (CAST(MONTH(""LOCAL_DATE"") AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-') ||[*] CAST(YEAR(""LOCAL_DATE"") AS VARCHAR(4))"; SQL statement:
CREATE FORCE VIEW (
    SELECT
        ((CAST(MONTH("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-') || CAST(YEAR("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(4))) AS "DATE"
    FROM "PUBLIC"."GENERIC_RECORD"
    GROUP BY (CAST(MONTH("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-') || CAST(YEAR("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(4))
) AS
SELECT
    ((CAST(MONTH("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-') || CAST(YEAR("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(4))) AS "DATE"
FROM "PUBLIC"."GENERIC_RECORD"
GROUP BY (CAST(MONTH("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(2)) || '-') || CAST(YEAR("LOCAL_DATE") AS VARCHAR(4)) [42000-200] 42000/42000 (Help)
```

The single nested SELECTs work just fine, but not when joined.

I'd like to get a table with columns {CATEGORY, DATE} where each distinct category is linked to every months

Comment: I would guess that you need table aliases.

Comment: Why not SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY in the second subquery as well?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think that I need to make one single line since I use JPA

Comment: @jarlh Because this is only a small part of a bigger query I need to make